# What's the function that is related to 3 as the Riemann zeta function is related to 2?

Tags: power-series, divergent-series, dirichlet-series, ramanujan-summation

For $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$, a real number $R\neq 1$, $g(x)=f(x)-Rf(x^2)$ Abel summable at $x=1$, $g(1)=\lim_{x\to 1^-} g(x)$, the elementary Ramanujan sum of $f(x)$ at $x=1$ is defined by $f(1)=g(1)/(1-R)$ ([definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342394/how-to-derive-sum-n-0-infty-1-frac12-without-zeta-regularization/1581114#1581114), also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623736/can-all-series-in-the-elementary-ramanujan-class-r-2-be-shifted)).

For
$$
f^{(N)}(x)=\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^N f(x)~,
$$
$f^{(N)}(1)=g^{(N)}(1)/(1-2^N R)$.

For $g(x)=x-x^2+x^3-\cdots=x/(1+x)$ ($|x|<1$) and $R=2$, we have
$f(x)=x+x^2+x^3+\cdots=x/(1-x)$ ($|x|<1$), $f(1)=-g(1)=-1/2$ and
$f^{(N)}(1)=\zeta(-N)$.

What we obtain if we replace $x^2$ with $x^3$ in the definition of the elementary Ramanujan summation? ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644968/in-what-sense-1-0-2-0-3-0-1-24))
For $g(x)=x-x^2+x^3-\cdots$ and $R=2$, what are $f_2(x)$ and $F_2(s)$ such that $f_2(x)-2f_2(x^3)=g(x)$ and $f_2^{(N)}(1)=F_2(-N)$? what are $f_3(x)$
and $F_3(s)$ such that $f_3(x)-3f_3(x^3)=g(x)$ and $f_3^{(N)}(1)=F_3(-N)$? ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664136/is-1-3-1-7-1-2-consistent-with-analytic-continuation) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670609/how-to-iterate-1-1-1-1-2-with-analytic-continuation-of-dirichlet-se))

How are $F_2(s)$ and $F_3(s)$ related to $\zeta(s)$?

Edit 1.
In general, for an odd prime number $p$ and $f(x)-Rf(x^p)=g(x)=x-x^2+x^3-\cdots$, the coefficients are given by $a_0=0$ and
$$
a_n=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{R^{m_p(n)+1}-1}{R-1}~,~~ (n>0)
$$
where $m_p(n)$ is the multiplicity of the prime factor $p$ of $n$.

The alternating series
$$
F_p(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}
$$
converges absolutely at least for $s>1$ and $|R|<p^s$.

The analytic continuation of the series
$G_p(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|n^{-s}$is given by
$$
G_p(s)=\frac{1}{1-Rp^{-s}}\zeta(s)~.
$$

Edit 2. $G_p(s)$ corresponds to $f(x)-Rf(x^p)=x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$. It generalizes the result about iteration and analytic continuation obtained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664136/is-1-3-1-7-1-2-consistent-with-analytic-continuation).

Comment: $H(s,y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} e^{-ny} = \int_1^\infty \lfloor x\rfloor (s x^{-s-1} e^{-xy}+x^{-s} ye^{-xy}) dx$. is it meromorphic as a function of $s$ and as a function of $y$? (if it is then its derivatives are too)

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you very much. Would you give me a on-line reference?

Comment: a reference for what ? it is only a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

For $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ and $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n$, $R\neq 1$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $k>1$, such that $f(x)-Rf(x^k)=g(x)$, the coefficients of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are recursively related by
$$
a_0=\frac{b_0}{1-R}~,~~ a_{kn+i}=b_{kn+i}\quad (0<i<k),~~ a_{kn+k}=b_{kn+k}+Ra_{n+1}~.
$$
The corresponding Dirichlet series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n n^{-s}$ satisfy
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}-R\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n (kn)^{-s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n n^{-s}~.
$$
Thus
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}=\frac{1}{1-Rk^{-s}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n n^{-s}
$$
and the corresponding analytic continuations $F(s)$ and $G(s)$ satisfy
$$
F(s)=\frac{1}{1-Rk^{-s}}G(s)~.
$$
For $g(x)=x-x^2+x^3-\cdots$ and $k=p\neq2$,
$$
F(s)=F_p(s)=\frac{1}{1-Rp^{-s}}\eta(s)=\frac{1-2^{1-s}}{1-Rp^{-s}}\zeta(s)~.
$$